# Travis gem deployment failing "Directory nonexistent"

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, travis-ci

I don't understand why the deployment is not working. I'm getting the following error in the build console:

```
Preparing deploy
Found gem 
/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash: 186: /usr/lib/git-core/git-stash: cannot create     /home/travis/build/prismicio/ruby-kit/.git/logs/refs/stash: Directory nonexistent
```

Build: https://travis-ci.org/prismicio/ruby-kit/jobs/40767391

My `.travis.yml`:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.1.1
- 2.1.0
- 2.0.0
- 1.9.3
- 1.9.2
- jruby-19mode
script: bundle exec rspec spec
notifications:
  email:
  - example@example.com
addons:
  code_climate:
    repo_token: X
deploy:
  provider: rubygems
  api_key:
    secure: XXX
  gemspec: prismic.gemspec
  on:
    tags: true
    all_branches: true
```

What's wrong with the build?

Comment: While there indeed seems to be an error in the logs, it seems like deploying the gem still worked, no?

Comment: I actually deployed it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> `/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash`: 186: `/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash`: cannot create     `/home/travis/build/prismicio/ruby-kit/.git/logs/refs/stash`: Directory nonexistent

may be related to how you're deploying your files to your provider and it's triggered by `git stash` and its `DPL::Provider#cleanup` process (see: [`releases.rb`](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/blob/b85c6cc/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb#L79)). By default [Deployment Provider](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl) will deploy the files from the latest commit. This is not supported for all providers, therefore this just means that the "releases" provider needs to skip the cleanup, so it should deploy from the current file state instead (see [@BanzaiMan comment](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1648#issuecomment-44917013)) by adding this line:

```
skip_cleanup: true
```

This is because every provider has slightly different flags and these are documented in the [Deployment section](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment) (or for the latest documentation check on [GitHub for supported providers](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#supported-providers)).

---

Further more, the above error is basically related to Travis CI bug (GH [#1648](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1648)) where basically [`File#basename`](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/blob/b85c6cc/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb#L79) is stripping the directory part (as per [@BanzaiMan comment](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1648#issuecomment-47457584)) and it's not clear why this cannot manifest in the CLI case. So this is something to fix in the near future.